# Embed react component into SVG via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to figure out how to embed a React component into an SVG image using purely JavaScript. I copied the [Semantic UI accordion example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion/#types-styled) into `example.js` (just copy/paste, no change to the example code) and now want to embed it into an SVG.

I can do this by adding it into the SVG directly

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AccordionExampleStyled from "./example"

export class MyView extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="App">
              <svg width="420" height="320">
                <foreignObject width="400" height="300">
                    <AccordionExampleStyled />
                </foreignObject>
              </svg>
            </div>
          );
    }
}
```

But I want to be able to use JavaScript to embed it into an existing SVG file, without touching the SVG file itself. I've tried mimicking the above code by simply creating an element of that type

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AccordionExampleStyled from "./example"
import { ReactComponent as MySvg } from './images/mysvg.svg';

export class MyView extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="App">
              <MySvg id="mySvg" />
            </div>
          );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var nestedObj = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject')
        nestedObj.setAttribute("x", "130")
        nestedObj.setAttribute("y", "199")
        nestedObj.setAttribute("width", "1000")
        nestedObj.setAttribute("height", "773.8095")

        var scnPg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", 'div')
        scnPg.style.fill = "red"
        scnPg.setAttribute("id", "scnPg")

        var accordion= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "AccordionExampleStyled")
        accordion.setAttribute("id", "accordion")
        accordion.style.position = "absolute"
        accordion.style.left = "0px"
        accordion.style.top = "0px"
        accordion.style.width = "1000px"
        accordion.style.height = "300px"
        scnPg.appendChild(accordion)

        var btn = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "button")
        btn.setAttribute("id", "tglBtn")
        btn.style.position = "absolute"
        btn.style.left = "0px"
        btn.style.top = "738px"
        btn.style.width = "90px"
        btn.style.height = "35px"
        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click Me!"))
        scnPg.appendChild(btn)

        document.getElementById("nodeToPlaceOver").parentElement.appendChild(nestedObj)
    }
}
```

The `button` works and appears as expected, however the `AccordionExampleStyled` is appearing as

```
<AccordionExampleStyled id="accordian" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 300px;"></AccordionExampleStyled>
```

Which, while literally exactly what I told it to do, is not the end result I'm hoping for. I'm assuming that `document.createElement` in this case would only work for HTML elements, and `AccordionExampleStyled` is a React element rather than an HTML one.

Is there some what to replicate the behavior seen at the top using a JavaScript "injection" approach?

**Update - createPortal**

As per Nikolay's suggestion, trying with createPortal. For brevity removed the button

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AccordionExampleStyled from "./example"
import { ReactComponent as MySvg } from './images/mysvg.svg';

export class MyView extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="App">
              <MySvg id="mySvg" />
            </div>
          );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        createPortal(<AccordionExampleStyled />, document.getElementById("A0100SCN0100").parentElement)
    }
}
```

No errors/complains, but it also doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not seeing any hint of the `AccordionExampleStyled` being added to the SVG.

Comment: A react component (JSX) is really just a series of Javascript operations react runs to create html. SVG is an image format that your web browser natively understands how to render. You have to choose which medium is appropriate for rendering your content... not try to embed one inside the other... its non-sensical

Comment: In my situation it makes sense to embed, as I use the SVG to create a scalable view of something (say a laptop) and I want to use HTML/React to create a facsimile of software that would appear on said view (such as the laptop monitor). Basically have a zoomable/scalable view of something which would contain a view of software. From my testing the approach outlined above would allow for this, I'm trying to find a more "reusable" approach to achieving this that would allow me to apply an arbitrary view (React component) over an arbitrary element in an SVG, without needing to modify the SVG.

Comment: @cantech gotcha. why not just use vanilla javascript function + template strings to generate SVG "components"? Seems like your not gaining any utility from react framework in this case esp. if you call something like .renderToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [createPortal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal), it mounts react component under specified DOM node (which may also happen to be an SVG node)

```js
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

var target = document.getElementById("myId"); // SVG target

createPortal(
  <foreignObject width="400" height="300">
    <AccordionExampleStyled />
  </foreignObject>, target); // mount react element
```

If you don't care about javascript (i.e. your element is not interactive, but just some static html) you can use "renderToString" and then just set `.innerHTML` to that.

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

const html = renderToString(<AccordionExampleStyled />);
target.innerHTML = html;
```

This is, most probably, not the case for the accordion, and you actually want it to be interactive.

Example which follows your code (you need to return the portal from render, and make sure your SVG exists before you use getElementById.

```
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return (<div>HELLO</div>)
}

function App() {

  const [fragment, setFragment] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const g = document.getElementById('nodeToPlaceOver');
    const fo = createPortal(
      <foreignObject width={100} height={100}>
        <MyComponent />
      </foreignObject>, 
      g);
    setFragment(fo);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g>
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" 
            strokeWidth="4" fill="yellow" />
          <g id="nodeToPlaceOver" />
        </g>
      </svg>
      {fragment}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried `createPortal(<AccordionExampleStyled />, document.getElementById("nodeToPlaceOver"))` and while it doesn't complain, it also doesn't seem to do anything. I can't find anything in the resulting SVG/HTML.

Comment: I assumed you have SVG it outside of your component. Note - you need to add the createPortal into your render function. I've added an example which follows your code.